# CloseHandle method for serial port blocking indefinitely when unplugging device

Tags: c++, serial-port, usb

I am currently facing issues with the `CloseHandle` method, trying to close a virtual serial port COM in C++. I use the methods `CreateFile` and `WriteFile` to send messages to my device. When my application closes, I call the `CloseHandle` method in my class destructor. Everything works fine when I close properly my application.

My device is plugged in the PC using a RJ45 to USB adaptor, which is plugged into the USB port of my computer. Then, I use a FTDI driver to communicate on a virtual serial COM port.

The issue occurs when I unplug the RJ45 cable from the adaptor: in this case, the `ReadFile` function correctly returns that it cannot communicate with the device; then, I want to close my application, calling the `CloseHandle` method. In this case, the `CloseHandle` method is blocking indefinitely and my application do not close. However, when I re-plugg the RJ45 cable, the `CloseHandle` method finishes and my application is able to close.

Something interesting is that I do not have the same issue when I unplug directly the USB port: in this case, the `CloseHandle` method works fine and my application closes.

Is there something in the communication buffer to clear in that case? (I have heard about the `EscapeCommFunction` method with the DTR signal or RTS signal but I tried this without success!) Why is `CloseHandle` blocking in this case? And why don't I have the same issue when I unplugg the USB cable?

I am not an expert in USB/serial communications, so please excuse the vocabulary.